# Is there a way to "Select all" the Apply Names in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

In Formulas->Define Name->Apply Names, I have thousands of custom named cells in the listbox. It is inefficient to select them allone by one. Is there a way, by setting in Excel or VBA code, to select them all? CTRL+A and SHIFT PgUp/Dn doesn't work.

In UserForm_Initialize(), I applied Cells.ApplyNames but error says 'Runtime error 1004, Microsoft Excel cannot find references to replace'

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The documentation at msdn.microsoft.com says

> Names: An array of the names to be applied. If this argument is omitted, all names on the sheet are applied to the range.

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196578(v=office.15).aspx

Following on that try this:

```
Selection.ApplyNames _
    IgnoreRelativeAbsolute:=True, UseRowColumnNames:=True, _
    OmitColumn:=True, OmitRow:=True, Order:=1, AppendLast:=False
```

This should work depending on the Scope of the Defined Names and their visibility. Try that and let us know the results.

Answer (score 0):

I found that combining a for loop with the ApplyNames Function worked for me.

```
Sub ApplyNames()
On Error Resume Next


Count = ActiveWorkbook.Names.Count

For i = 1 To Count

    Name = ActiveWorkbook.Names.Item(i).Name

    Cells.applynames Names:=Array(Name), IgnoreRelativeAbsolute:=False

Next i

End Sub
```

It counts the number of names then loops through them individually.

For some reason leaving the names variable empty didn't work in my situation, I think it was because there were errors in some of the names.